The road was open again, but may as well have remained closed, such were the delays

The road was open again, but may as well have remained closed, such were the delays.

(https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/c7f92c0dde0c4c2e9878e6809728f425)
What's the meaning of the sentence and how can this be analyzed in terms of the grammar and syntax (including "such" usage)?

Your source is a dictionary.  The purpose of examples in dictionaries is to illustrate the meaning of words.  The meaning is as given in the definition.  "used to indicate that a situation is the same as if the hypothetical thing stated were true".  You ask for the meaning in context.  But a dictionary does not provide context.

Presumably the road in question had been closed because of some kind of blockage, and then re-opened, but it was still taking a very long time for traffic to pass along it. So the delays were so great that it didn't make much difference that the road was open.
Personally, I would have used might as well. (May = present tense, might = past tense).

What's the usage of 'such'?

"of such a kind", here implying "so great", as I put in my paraphrase.

The 'such' here is related with 'may as well'?

And why did you use 'that' instead of 'when' in "didn't make much difference that the road was open."?

The fact that the road was open didn't make much difference to the situation. The delays were such (i.e. so great) that the road might as well have remained closed.

You omitted 'to the fact' before "that the road was open"?

(Sighs) I only put the fact in to show why I used that - it isn't needed in the sentence.

I don't understand why you used 'that' after '...make much difference' because your 'that' clause of "that the road was open" is a noun clause; in other words, it's not an adjectival relative clause here and I've never seen this structure: have much difference that s+v.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As I answered you in this question three days ago,
“You can understand such to mean roughly ‘the type.’”
So the passage means that the delays were of the type [in other words, so severe] that the road may as well have remained closed.

I was confused with the clause ", such were the delays." because of inversion. I think the original version is "the delays were such"(such went to front and inversion happend between the subject the delays and the stative 'to be', "were" , here. This is my analysis.
